# Expected value caluclation

Tags: calculus, probability

I needed help with this problem [image]

Basically I have to show that $E(X^2-3x+2)=E(X^2)-3E(X)+2=\frac{2p^2}{(1-p)^2}$. 
I know that  $E(X^2-3x+2)=E(X^2)-3E(X)+2=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^2(p^{x-1}-p^x)-3\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x(p^{x-1}-p^x)+2$. I have no idea how to use $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dp} P(X)=0$ and $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^2}{dp^2} P(X)=0$. I would like some sort of hint thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^2 p^{x-1} = p\ \underbrace{\Big(x(x-1)p^{x-2}\Big)+xp^{x-1}}_{\large\text{This is }\dfrac{d^2}{dp^2} p^x + \dfrac{d}{dp} p^x}
$$
And $xp^{x-1}=\dfrac{d}{dp} p^x$.

Comment: Just to make things a bit more clear $\frac{d}{dp}=(x-1)p^{x-2}-xp^{x-1}$ and $\frac{d^2}{dp^2}=(x-1)(x-2)p^{x-3}-(x)(x-1)p^{x-2}$.

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I can't seem to fit $\frac{d^2}{dp^2} p^{x-1}$ and $\frac{d}{dp} p^{x-1}$ into this problem.

Comment: Why do you want to fit the derivatives of $p\mapsto p^{x-1}$ into the problem? The parts above about derivatives of $p\mapsto p^x$ should do it, except for $xp^x$, which is $(x+1)p^x - p^x = \left(\dfrac{d}{dp} p^{x+1}\right)-p^x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Verify that
$$ P'(k) = (k-1)\frac{P(k)}{p} - p^{k-1}$$
$$ P''(k) = (k-1)(k-2)\frac{P(k)}{p^2} -2\left[\frac{P'(k) + p^{k-1}}{1-p}\right] $$

You can derive these by observing patterns when differentiating. Anyhow, sum on both sides, rearrange, to get your answer.